# Weird JSON, how to access needed value

Tags: json

This is the JSON response:

[image]

I need to access `data[1]`, which is `0.2`. How do I get it?

Here's the actual code:

```
function getTheValue(){
    var result = $.ajax({ url: "https://www.blahblah.com/json" });
    return result;
}

console.log(getTheValue());
```

Here's another way I tried, no luck:

```
var val = getTheValue();
console.log(val.responseJSON.dataset.data[0][1]);
```

Comment: Autocomplete doesn't give you any hints?

Comment: @Taraz, жоқ, дым бермейді.

Answer (score 0):

The response you're seeing is the ajax object, not the return from the function.  $.ajax is asynchronous, so the value isn't available until immediately.

Adapted from [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: your_url,
})
.done(function( result ) {
  console.log( result );
});
```

will give you result.  Your subsequent code will need to be triggered inside that done() function.

Comment: Nope, it says `undefined`.

Comment: What do val.responseJSON.dataset.data[0] and val.responseJSON.dataset.data say?

Comment: both `undefined`. Tried `val.responseJSON`, no luck as well

Comment: What about just val?

Comment: just `val` prints me what I posted as image :) whole object :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100198/discussion-between-jimm101-and-seattlesam).

Answer (score 0):

That object isn't json in its common sense but an Javascript object, if you want the ajax result you have to use a callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.blahblah.com/json" ,
  dataType: "json",
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getTheValue` function is not returning the JSON response from the AJAX call. It is returning a `promise` object, since it is actually a doing an asynchronous call. I suggest you read documentation for [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more information.

Anyway, you can fix your problem by doing this:

```
var val;
getTheValue().done(function(response) {
    val = response.dataset.data[0][1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This finally helped me:

```
var tBill = getTheBill();

    function getTheBill(){
        var result;
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "https://www.blahblah.com/json",
            context: document.body,
            async: false
        }).done(function(val) {
            result = val;
        });
        return result.dataset.data[0][1];
    }
```

Guys, thanks for your help! `jimm101`, you rock.

Comment: Requesting your json synchronous will block your page eg. mouse events and animations thus using async: false is considered deprecated